# MSDeploy ALWAYS updating certain information?

Tags: msdeploy

I'm using MSDeploy to keep IIS Servers in sync.   But, I'm receiving these messages all of the time now:

```
Info: Deleting binding (MSDeploy.appHostConfig/appHostConfig[@path='Default Web Site']/site[@name='Default Web Site']/bindings/binding).
Info: Adding child bindings (MSDeploy.appHostConfig/appHostConfig[@path='Default Web Site']/site[@name='Default Web Site']/bindings/binding).
```

I'm just doing the following:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:apphostconfig="Default Web Site" -dest:apphostconfig="Default Web Site",computername=[removeddestination]
```

The source server is 2008 and the destination is 2012.  Is this normal?  Or am I missing something.

I looked at the applicationHost.config files and they are about as close to being the same as I think the can be, realizing that they are different OSes and all.

This is just one example.   I have several different updates that it says it's doing, but it really should be the same thing.  All of them are of the "Updating Application" variety.

Thanks for any assistance.

Nick

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the `-verbose` flag to your msdeploy call to get more details about why its deleting and reading the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I took the -verbose command and added it to my deploy to figure out just what was causing it to show up.   Seems almost all of them are items that were added in IIS 8.0.   (And I'm on 7.5 of course).   So I'll just take that as being an "expected" solution.

Thanks!